# Easiest way to build / obtain php_memcache.dll for PHP 5.4

Tags: php, windows, dll, build

I'm planning to use Traits, available in PHP 5.4 on our application that requires Memcache and hence php_memcache.dll

I'm developing on a Windows machine using PHP 5.4 latest release candidate.

I am unable to source a PHP 5.4 build of php_memcache.dll so would like to know either how to obtain it or failing that, build it myself (the instructions on http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.building.php seem a little lacking!).

I do not have Visual Studio or any build tools installed on my machine (and ideally do not want to pay for any).

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found a working mem cached dll for 5.4.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doc page explains how to do it: http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

But the best way to easily achieve this would be to run ubuntu/fedora as a virtual os (using virtualbox). Getting newer versions of any extensions will be way easier under unix.

You could still develop on windows and use a shared directory to run the php code in the linux VM.

Comment: I followed the instructions (except I wasn't sure on step 16:

configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-$remains

what the $remains variable was, so removed it).

After extracting http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache and running

configure --enable-cli --enable-memcache

nmake

I'm stuck with error

c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\pecl\memcache-3.0.6\memcache_pool.h(37) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems you are missing the standard c library. It might be an addon with Microsoft Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

It seems PECL/memcache 3.0.5 and 3.0.6 don't compile properly under Windows (at least not with the instructions provided in [PHP's Wiki](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild)). Version [2.2.6](http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache-2.2.6.tgz%202.2.6) does appear to compile properly.

Follow the instructions in the Wiki and use this configure string:

```
--enable-cli-win32 --disable-zts --disable-isapi --disable-nsapi --without-mssql --without-pdo-mssql --without-pi3web --disable-static-analyze --enable-memcache=shared
```

That should give you a "php_memcache.dll" compatible with PHP 5.4.0 (VC9, non thread-safe). These options (with some small modifications) were taken from the build configuration of the Win32 binaries provided on PHP.net.

The extension loads without errors in PHP 5.4.0RC6, but I haven't actually (stress-)tested it in any meaningful way...