# php_memcache.dll for zf2.0 and php5.4

Tags: php, zend-framework, memcached, zend-framework2

I use memcached, the previous environment (xampp1.73) php5.3 and zf1. No problem. I upgraded php5.4 and zf2, the memcached module error, how can I do? Who can give me a support php5.4 the memcache.dll

Comment: The error message is as follows:"PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module.
Module compiled with build ID=API20090206,TS,vc6
PHP compiled with build ID=API20090206,TS,vc9
These options need to match"

Comment: I need your help.zf2 to use php which version?  我现在用的是php5.4的.但是5.4不能用memcached.I have to use memcached. How can I do?

Comment: Any links to a PHP 5.4 memcache.dll file would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Who help me compile an up-to-date memcache.dll file? Can support php5.4.

Comment: You probably need to recompile memcache.dll. The following post is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966532/easiest-way-to-build-obtain-php-memcache-dll-for-php-5-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your module is compiled with Visual Studio 6 Compiler (VC6) but PHP5.4 is compiled with Visual Studio 9 Compiler (VC9), and so the module is incompatible with your PHP.  You will need to compile Memcached using the Visual Studio 9 compiler.

See this thread for information on how to get the correct Memcache DLL for your PHP: [Easiest way to build / obtain php_memcache.dll for PHP 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966532/easiest-way-to-build-obtain-php-memcache-dll-for-php-5-4)

Comment: zend sever  自带编译好的php_memcache.dll 拓展，支持PHP 5.4。